# How to display the number of new emails in Google's new app INBOX

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Can anybody please tell me how to display the number of new messages in Google's new web app **Inbox**?normally with Google's Gmail,you get to see the number of new emails.please see the screenshot of Gmail I've attached below.i would like **Inbox** to display the same thing as Google gmail.

**Screenshot from Gmail -**

[image: gmail]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.